# Laravel Authentication - Auth::check returns FALSE

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm fairly new to `Laravel` and I'm currently working on a manual authentication for my project.
I have tried `Auth::attempt` to validate the credentials that have been input, and I have seen that it works since I am being redirected to the page I wanted when it is authenticated.

However, when I try to do `Auth::check` in the view I have been redirected to, it seems that it returns FALSE and does not read the authenticated user. This makes the certain portion of that view to not be visible. Any insights on this one? Thanks a lot!

Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;    
class LoginController extends Controller
{   //    
    public function index()
    {
        return view('view_login');
    }    

    public function verify(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');    
         if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect('dashboard');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }
```

View

```
@if (Auth::check())
     <li><a href="dashboard.html"> Hello {{ Auth::user()->username }}  </a></li>
@endif
```

Current Result:
[image]

Expected Result:
[image]

Update:
I've tried to put `dd(auth()->user());` after authentication, and I have seen the attributes of the authenticated user. However, after putting this on the Dashboard Controller, it returns NULL. Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: It should work there is no issue in the code. Use this command if the view is cached php artisan view:clear

Comment: I tried to clear it, unfortunately it still does not show

Comment: Try this in view : auth()->check() or \Auth::check()

Comment: Still doesn’t seem to work. ☹️

Comment: After authentication did you go to the dashboard page? and remove the line on the top of the controller: use Auth; and then try.

Comment: Are you sure your View Code inside view of route dashboard ?

Comment: Did you changed email to username for users table ?

Comment: Yes, it did go to the dashboard page after authentication. I have added an image in the question above to show what is the expected and the current result that I am having.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the primary key of your users database. If you set your table's primary key other than `id`, you need to set it in your User model.

The Laravel Documentation states the following:

`Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column named id. You may define a protected $primaryKey property to override this convention.`

For example, if you have a user_id column set as your primary key in your users database, you need to place the code below in the User model:

`protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';`

Answer (score 0):

Actually your Authentication works fine, because you can print hello when user authenticated. 
If you want to prevent access of **unauthenticated user** you can do this.
add this function as the first function of your controller

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

or you can check user in route

```
Route::get('admin/profile', function () {
    //
})->middleware('auth');
```

by this ways just authenticated user can see the dashboard page.

Comment: It authenticates and goes to the dashboard page, however, the certain portion of view with the if condition still does not show

Comment: I'm not having any error. I've added images to the question to show the expected and current result that I have.

Comment: Hi, the "Hello User" is what I want and what I expect, however, it is not currently showing after authenticating as shown in the other image.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use Laravel's verification & write your own code in function [authenticated](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.html#method_authenticated) instead.

FYI, function [attemptLogin](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.html#method_attemptLogin) need to be call so that user can login.